# Automatically display only the latest topic

Tags: react-native, expo

I need to show only the latest content posted in my website using API to display it on my react native mobile app home page. But when I run my app it shows Typeerror: undefined is not an object this.state.persons[0].p_pages_title.

Below is a sample of my json data:

```
{
statuc: "SUCCESS",
data: - [
- {
p_pages_id: "6591",
p_pages_title: "د شوال شپږ روژې نیول (الحدیث).",
p_pages_author: "تعلیم الاسلام",
p_pages_date: "2019-06-08 05:45:11",

},
- {
p_pages_id: "10122",
p_pages_title: "د رسول اللهﷺ تبسم (الحدیث)",
p_pages_author: "تعلیم الاسلام ",
p_pages_date: "2019-06-04 20:10:43",

},
- {
p_pages_id: "2798",
p_pages_title: "تر درو ورځو زیاته خوابدتیا (الحدیث).",
p_pages_author: "تعلیم الاسلام",
p_pages_date: "2019-06-04 10:25:03",

},
- {
p_pages_id: "3871",
p_pages_title: "د لیلة القدر د شپې دعا (الحدیث)",
p_pages_author: "تعلیم الاسلام ویب پاڼه",
p_pages_date: "2019-05-29 09:06:47",

},
- {
p_pages_id: "10095",
p_pages_title: "د روژې د هري شپې اعلان (الحدیث).",
p_pages_author: "تعلیم الاسلام ویب پاڼه",
p_pages_date: "2019-05-15 05:41:06",

},
- {
p_pages_id: "5357",
p_pages_title: "د ریان دروازه د روژاتي لپاره (الحدیث).",
p_pages_author: "تعلیم الاسلام راډیو",
p_pages_date: "2019-05-12 04:59:24",

},
```

And here is the code:

```
class DailyHadith extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      persons: [],
      isLoading: true,

    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {


    axios
      .get(`address of the json data`)
      .then(res => {
        // console.log(res);
        this.setState({
          isLoading: false,
          persons: res.data.data
        });
      });


  }
```

// Here is the render method:

```
render(){

return (

<Card>


<CardItem>

<Text>{this.state.persons[0].p_pages_title}</Text>

</CardItem>

</Card>
    );
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please Edit your code properly

Comment: return only the latest one from the server

Comment: as @JaromandaX said: return only the latest 

Or you can just return data[data.length-1] to take the latest one, if they are sorted by date

Comment: @Margon Sorry but i am junior where to put data[data.length-1] please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your data has a field named : p_pages_date which can be used for fetching the latest data. 
Create a new state as latestData. And you can use the below code to filter the latest data.

```
       axios.get(`address of the json data`)
           .then(res => {
             // console.log(res);
             let latestDataValue = {};
             if(res.length){
             c = res.reduce((m,v,i) => (v.p_pages_date > 
              m.p_pages_date) && i ? v : m).ModDate;
            }
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                persons: res.data.data,
                latestData:latestDataValue
            });
         });
```

Now in your render method call this.state.latestData.p_pages_title instead of this.state.persons[0].p_pages_title

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nothing display. can you explain your code please. latestDataValue is not populated with data right. it seems empty.